# Vue js: search filter according to multiple attributes not working properly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a search functionality here in Vue js for data coming from API and it works fine on a single data item (`question.questionTitle`)  but my problem is I can't figure out how to apply it on all data like `question.name`, `question.desc`... is there a way to do it?

```html
<template>

        <ul 

          class="container-question" 
          v-for="(question, index) in questions"
          :key="index" 
        
        >
              <div v-for="(questions,index) in filteredList" :key="index">
        ......
        
        </div>
        </ul>
</template>

<script>
  filteredList() {
       return  this.questions.filter(question => {
        return question.questionTitle.includes(this.search)
      })
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `||` to check for the search result in other fields:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data() {
    return {
      search: '',
      questions: [
        { 
          questionTitle: "title1", 
          name: "name1", 
          desc: "desc1",
          categories: [
            { category_name: "category1a" },
            { category_name: "category1b" }
          ]
        },
        { 
          questionTitle: "title2", 
          name: "name2", 
          desc: "desc2",
          categories: [
            { category_name: "category2a" },
            { category_name: "category2b" }
          ]
        },
        { 
          questionTitle: "title3", 
          name: "name3", 
          desc: "desc3",
          categories: [
            { category_name: "category3a" },
            { category_name: "category3b" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredList() {
      const search = this.search;
      return search===''
        ? this.questions
        : this.questions.filter(question => 
            question.questionTitle.includes(search) ||
            question.name.includes(search) ||
            question.desc.includes(search) ||
            question.categories.some(category =>
              category.category_name.includes(search)
            )
          )
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
 <div class="search-wrapper">
   <label>Search title:</label>
   <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search title.."/>
  </div>
  <ul  class="container-question">
    <li v-for="(question,questionIndex) in filteredList" :key="questionIndex">
      {{question.questionTitle}} - {{question.name}} - {{question.desc}}
      <div 
        class="category"               
        v-for="(allCategories, categoryIndex) in question.categories"           
        v-bind:key="categoryIndex"
      >               
        <mark> {{ allCategories.category_name }} </mark>             
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but i'm having problem now that each question coming from api is repeated 4 times

Comment: @seran99 I don't think it has to do with this. Make sure you're getting the list correctly, defining ``questions:[]`` in ``data`` and setting it after the request is done

Comment: i updated my code above , i tried to put ' <div v-for="(questions,index) in filteredList" :key="index">' before ul but it didn't work

Comment: @seran99 you only need to iterate over ``filteredList`` as above

Comment: That's the function of the computed ``filteredList``. In case no input was added to the search it returns the ``questions``, otherwise, it returns the filtered version matching

Comment: it worked thank u, i have also categories array but the search isn't working on them    `<div class="category"
              v-for="(allCategories, index) in question.categories" 
              v-bind:key="index"
              @click="selectedCategory(allCategories._id)" >
              <mark> {{ allCategories.category_name }} </mark>
            </div>`      i'm trying to filter them like this `question.categories.some((cat) => cat.category_name === this.search)`

Comment: @seran99 I updated the answer to support categories as well

Comment: Please mark the answer as the solution if it solves the problem or reply if there's anything missing

Comment: @seran99 check the demo above, it checks for the matches in each category of a question

Comment: yes i tried it categories not working on search

Comment: Describe what "working" is for categories? Shouldn't the first element only appear when entering ``category1`` for example?

Comment: when i'm searching on category name it's not applying the search on it

Comment: @seran99 you didn't answer the question? Isn't the above example that I gave valid in this implementation? I mean entering a category of an item applies the filter